# How do I add an href to my .js file?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, href

I need to add a link to a few quotes in a .js file that says "more". The link will redirect the user to the testimonials page where they can read the full testimonial. I'm not sure how to add a link directly in the .js file, because when I add an href it doesn't work. As you can tell, I'm not a Javascript guy, so please pardon my obvious stupidity :)

Here is the code for the quotes:

```
`({"quotes":
 [
    {
    "quote" : "Quote 1 Here... <a href="/testimonials">more</a>",
    "author" : "Persons Name"
    }
 ]
 })`
```

Comment: That's not a JS file. That's a json string. It's a textual representation of a javascript data structure. You DON'T manipulate JSON directly. Instead, you manipulate the original data structure and then regenerate the JSON version of it.

Comment: Sorry for the verbage error Marc, and thanks for your comment. Learning as I go :) I assumed to call it a js file because it has a filename that ends in .js. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to put " inside the JSON data content, then you need to escape it, or use single quotes ', otherwise the double quotes in the middle will close the JSON value.

```
`({"quotes":
 [
    {
    "quote" : "Quote 1 Here... <a href='/testimonials'>more</a>",
    "author" : "Persons Name"
    }
 ]
 })`
```

But as stated above, you should do this by editing the object in javascript and reproducing the JSON in the correct format.

Comment: Single quotes did it. I feel stupid for having not thought of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make any sense.  Javascript strings are ordinary strings and are not aware of any formatting details.

You probably want to set the **HTML** (not text) of a DOM element.  Beware of the resulting XSS hole.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make sense in my question. I only know HTML and CSS, so adding an href to the Javascript didn't work. It turns out all I had to do is turn the double quotes into single quotes. Thanks for your comment none the less.